# How to update form with errors in Django?

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to write an is_valid method for my forms and I'm using this general strategy:

```
def is_valid(self):
    form = super(UserCreateForm, self).is_valid()
    for f, error in self.errors.iteritems():
        if f!= '__all__':
            self.fields[f].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'error', 'value': strip_tags(error)})
    return form
```

I want to update the form fields' attributes if I get an error with helpful attributes. But I already have class attributes for the fields (using Bootstrap, so something like 'class':'form-control'); I want the error to replace them. However, when I fail the validation and actually get an error, Django complains saying can't concatenate str and errorList. I'm a bit new to Django, so I'm not sure what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

The way i do this is, have the the errors checked at all the individual divs and display bootstrap's .error class if i find a error. 
Eg:{% if form.error %}

Like that you check it with every filed name. 
Note: There might be better ways to do it, but i have been using this for a long time now and has worked fine.